# error to generate angular project with jhipster v8.1.0

Tags: jhipster

I try to use the new version of jhipster with angular.
i use angular 17.0.2 jhipster 8.1.0 node 18.18.2 but when i generate the project i get this error:
ERROR! An error occured while running jhipster:bootstrap#commitPrettierConfig
ERROR! ERROR! Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'CLIOptions': Cannot find module 'typescript'
[image]

i can not fix this error so i need your help

Comment: You don't need any pre-installed version of Angular since JHipster will take care of that and install the proper Angular version for the JHipster version that you run. Create a new folder, navigate into that, and execute npm install generator-jhipster. After that, use the local JHipster by running ./node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/cli/jhipster.cjs just to be sure that it is not interfering with other installations on your system.